# How can I dynamically construct a Scala class without knowing types in advance?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I want to build a simple library in which a developer can define a Scala class that represents command line arguments (to keep it simple, just a single set of required arguments -- no flags or optional arguments). I'd like the library to parse the command line arguments and return an instance of the class. The user of the library would just do something like this:

```
case class FooArgs(fluxType: String, capacitorCount: Int)

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val argsObject: FooArgs = ArgParser.parse(args).as[FooArgs]
  // do real stuff 
}
```

The parser should throw runtime errors if the provided arguments do not match the expected types (e.g. if someone passes the string "bar" at a position where an `Int` is expected).

How can I dynamically build a `FooArgs` without knowing its shape in advance? Since `FooArgs` can have any arity or types, I don't know how to iterate over the command line arguments, cast or convert them to the expected types, and then use the result to construct a `FooArgs`. Basically, I want to do something along these lines:

```
// ** notional code - does not compile **
def parse[T](args: Seq[String], klass: Class[T]): T = {
  val expectedTypes = klass.getDeclaredFields.map(_.getGenericType)
  val typedArgs = args.zip(expectedTypes).map({
      case (arg, String)      => arg
      case (arg, Int)         => arg.toInt
      case (arg, unknownType) => 
        throw new RuntimeException(s"Unsupported type $unknownType")
  })
  (klass.getConstructor(typedArgs).newInstance _).tupled(typedArgs)
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to abstract over `case class` (or `Tuple`) shape, the standard approach is to get the `HList` representation of the `case class` with the help of `shapeless` library. `HList` keeps track in its type signature of the types of its elements and their amount. Then you can implement the algorithm you want recursively on the `HList`. Shapeless also provides a number of helpful transformations of `HList`s in `shapeless.ops.hlist`.

For this problem, first we need to define an auxiliary typeclass to parse an argument of some type from `String`:

```
trait Read[T] {
  def apply(str: String): T
}

object Read {
  def make[T](f: String => T): Read[T] = new Read[T] {
    def apply(str: String) = f(str)
  }

  implicit val string: Read[String] = make(identity)

  implicit val int: Read[Int] = make(_.toInt)
}
```

You can define more instances of this typeclass, if you need to support other argument types than `String` or `Int`.

Then we can define the actual typeclass that parses a sequence of arguments into some type:

```
// This is needed, because there seems to be a conflict between
// HList's :: and the standard Scala's ::
import shapeless.{:: => :::, _}

trait ParseArgs[T] {
  def apply(args: List[String]): T
}

object ParseArgs {
  // Base of the recursion on HList
  implicit val hnil: ParseArgs[HNil] = new ParseArgs[HNil] {
    def apply(args: List[String]) =
      if (args.nonEmpty) sys.error("too many args")
      else HNil
  }

  // A single recursion step on HList
  implicit def hlist[T, H <: HList](
    implicit read: Read[T], parseRest: ParseArgs[H]
  ): ParseArgs[T ::: H] = new ParseArgs[T ::: H] {
    def apply(args: List[String]) = args match {
      case first :: rest => read(first) :: parseRest(rest)
      case Nil => sys.error("too few args")
    }
  }

  // The implementation for any case class, based on its HList representation
  implicit def caseClass[C, H <: HList](
    implicit gen: Generic.Aux[C, H], parse: ParseArgs[H]
  ): ParseArgs[C] = new ParseArgs[C] {
    def apply(args: List[String]) = gen.from(parse(args))

  }
}
```

And lastly we can define some API, that uses this typeclass. For example:

```
case class ArgParser(args: List[String]) {
  def to[C](implicit parseArgs: ParseArgs[C]): C = parseArgs(args)
}

object ArgParser {
  def parse(args: Array[String]): ArgParser = ArgParser(args.toList)
}
```

And a simple test:

```
scala> ArgParser.parse(Array("flux", "10")).to[FooArgs]
res0: FooArgs = FooArgs(flux,10)
```

There is a great guide on using `shapeless` for solving similar problems, which you may find helpful: [The Type Astronaut’s Guide to Shapeless](https://openlibra.com/es/book/the-type-astronauts-guide-to-shapeless)

Comment: Yeeha! I <3 you, Internet. This works perfectly, though it will take me a month to understand what's going on here.